# How to wait for element not present using Playwright

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, playwright, playwright-python

I need to translate Selenium code into Playwright.

code:

```
self.wait_for_element_not_present("element CSS here")
```

Is the solution:

```
Not self.page.locator("element CSS here").is_visible()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [not_be_visible](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/test-assertions#locator-assertions-not-to-be-visible) expect assertion for this.

```py
expect('element CSS here').not_to_be_visible()
```

By default expect assertions have a 5 second timeout, in case you want to increase the timeout, you can do like this:

```py
expect('element CSS here').not_to_be_visible(timeout=7000)
```